# Add and refresh data in dropdownlist using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to add data in drop down list,I am able to add the data and view it but for that i have to refresh the page again, I want to do that in jQuery without refreshing the page.

Comment: Usual question: What have you tried? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Please add the code you have already written to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find useful [this](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jQuery method. Also it is a good practice to use template engines such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to clean up your javascript code and separate it from mark-up.

Comment: Have tried this method but by using this method the Id assigned to the value in drop down in not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code**

**In html file**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post( "countries.php", function( data ) {
                            $("#countries").html(data);
                            //console.log(data);
                        });
});
</script>
```

**In countries.php**

```
    <?php
     include("config.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $countryArr = array();
    $options = "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $options .= "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'>".$row['country_title']."</option>";
    }
    echo $options;
 ?>
```